# flutter get user email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

i want to get my flutter login form user id into a text box.i used firebase to make authentication. i wrote a method to get user email.

```
  _getUserEmail(){

    FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return new Text(snapshot.data.email);
        }
        else {
          return new Text('Loading...');
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

i want to get this user email into my flutter textbox view initial value. This is my flutter textbox.

```
ListTile(
       leading: Icon(Icons.info),
       title: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Enter Your name'
         ),
          initialValue: _getUserEmail(),
           onSaved: (val) => item.name = val,
           validator: (val) => val == "" ? val : null,
         ),
        ),
```

i want to get my email into ListTile initial value. can anyone help me?

Comment: It seems to me that if you get a valid 'currentUser' that the user is already authenticated and therefore should not have to login again. If the user had logged-in in the past and the login has expired or the user logged-out, you could save the email in 'shared preferences` https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/key-value/ and retrieve from there to display in form.

Comment: i want to get login email and save it in my firebase object. i can get user login email. but it cannot showing in my textbox. i used _getUserEmail method. but it cannot use in flutter textbox initial value

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a direct answer to your question. But using a form with validation for async authentication requires particular management of the validators to handle the async result. I but together a demo of how to manage the validators. The demo simulates the async call, so you would have to implement the firebase auth for your particular app. Might be a useful reference if still having problems.

[image]

You can find source code [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/modal_progress_hud#-example-tab-)

Edit: I created an [example](https://gist.github.com/mmcc007/decd89b5f23c69d87ce207fd582e6b20) showing how to preload the form by inserting a widget that makes an async call.
[image]

I also got it to work using a [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) too, but this seemed cleaner. There are other ways to do it too.

Comment: i'm also make my login and redirect to my home page. but i want to display login user email into my home page textfield. that's my question. but anyway thank you for your answer. it supports me another.